# Accessing RedShift Table inside UDF

Tags: python, amazon-redshift, amazon-rds

I have 2 tables:

1. Main Table
2. Rules Reference Table(if, else if, else)

I cannot join tables directly because reference tables contains if,else if condition data.

Same functionality i have implemented using Distributed Cache UDF in HIVE and i want same behavior in RedShfit also.

I want to apply Reference rules table for each and every Main table rows.

Whether can i access entire reference table inside UDF?

Answer (score 0):

Currently it's impossible to access underlining db from UDF on RedShift, not supported yet.